# Symfony mergin two entities into one form and retrieving their data to push to db

Tags: forms, symfony

I have 2 entities where i want to retrieve thier data from the same form so i created a common formType for both entities

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('offer', OfferType::class)
            ->add('funding', FundingType::class)
            ->add('Submit', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }
```

my problem is in the common controller where i want to retrieve the data from the form and push it to db this is where i'm at right now.

```
#[Route('/new', name: 'app_offer_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $offer = new Offer();
        $funding = new Funding();
        $form = $this->createForm(OfferFundingType::class, ['offer' => $offer, 'funding' => $funding]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $formData = $form->getData();
            $formData->setDateCreated(new \DateTime());
            $entityManager->persist($offer);
            $entityManager->persist($funding);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_offer_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }
```

But this is wrong because createForm methode dosen't take arrays for data
(create form documentation):

```
 protected function createForm(string $type, $data = null, array $options = []): FormInterface
    {
        return $this->container->get('form.factory')->create($type, $data, $options);
    }
```